# React-Native-Navigation Icon Alignment

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I've been using react-native-navigation in my current react native app and I'm running into a problem. I have a navbar on my app with the left button as a toggle for the drawer menu and the right button is a logo linking to our company website.

The logo is set in the navbar as follows:

```
icon: require('../logos/BB-Icon.png')
```

When viewing the app on android I get the following result
[as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUO5G.jpg).

However, on iOS I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHAzj.png).

I have searched through the docs and can't seem to find anything that will centre the navbar in iOS in the same way as Android.

Environment:

- React Native Navigation version: 1.1.444
- React Native version: 0.52.0
- Device Info: Android: Samsung Galaxy S9 running Android 8.0.0 // iOS: iPhone X simulator running iOS 11.3

Answer (score 0):

In 2.17, you can modify `lib/ios/RNNUIBarButtonItem.m` like this:

```
-(instancetype)init:(NSString*)buttonId withIcon:(UIImage*)iconImage {
    UIButton* button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setImage:iconImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, iconImage.size.width, iconImage.size.height)];
    self = [super initWithCustomView:button];
    self.buttonId = buttonId;
// Align left or right here.
    button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    return self;
}
```

I don't know if you can do something similar in version 1.x though.  Hopefully this will help.